# wxDC plot a waveform wxwidgets

Tags: c++, plot, wxwidgets, waveform, portaudio

Hello I use CodeBLocks + WxWidgets + Portaudio . I want to draw a wavefrom during the record the voice from microphone. How do it ?
I have information about recordedSamples
I think that I should use a wxDc but i can't because  i never see example with it. I understand somethin when i saw example. 
Please show me example with wxDC ( plot something ) or if you want help me more and show how drawing a waveform. I know how record from microphon and hava a record samples and other necessery things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing sample included in wxWidgets shows how to use `wxDC`. You can see at how plotting is done by looking at the sources of any of the various plotting libraries for wxWidgets and, perhaps, you should consider just using one of them instead of doing this on your own.